# Add a custom executable bash script and its systemd script to Yocto Build

Tags: bash, embedded-linux, yocto

I have written a simple script to use a 3G UMTS Dongle with my board.

The bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1;
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s Cloud
/usr/bin/tmux set-option set-remain-on-exit on
/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'usb_modeswitch' -t Cloud:2 '/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch --default-vendor 12d1 --default-product 1446 -J';

/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'wvdial' -t Cloud:1 'sleep 10; /usr/bin/wvdialconf; /usr/bin/wvdial';
```

and its corresponding `systemd` script is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable UMTS Dongle for Cloud Connectivity

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/umts.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have other such `systemd` files for certain applications files that I have currently written **directly** on the board but want them to be available for every image I make for new board.

How should I go around with this in terms of a recipe?

I thought of creating my own Yocto layer:

```
   meta-custom
       ------ recipes-custom/
                     ------------- files / all such scripts here

               ------------  custom_1.0.bb
```

Should I only perform `do_install()` the bash scripts in the `custom_1.0.bb` recipes? since the scripts do not require to be compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating own layer is a good idea and structure you listed is fine too.

in your recipes you can create empty do_compile and do_configure tasks\
here is a pseudo recipe. And dont forget to add it to IMAGE_INSTALL in
the end so that your image build picks it up as dependency.

```
SRC_URI = "file://file.service \
           file://file.sh \
          "
inherit systemd

do_configure(){
  :
}

do_compile() {
  :
}

do_install() {
    install -Dm 0644 ${WORKDIR}/<file.service> ${D}/${systemd_unitdir}/system/<file.service>
    install -Dm 0755 ${WORKDIR}/<file.sh> ${D}/${bindir}/<file.sh>
    ...
}

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "<file.service>"
```

Comment: This pushes systemd scripts to the image but what about the `umts.sh` to say `/usr/bin/` folder I can just use `install` there too? An will that require a separate recipe?

Comment: I was looking into the mega-manual and this was exactly what needed to be done. I think for pre-compiled third-party binaries one just might need to use `inherit bin_package`. (Side note for someone viewing this query in the future)